# How Do I Handle Windows 7's 125% or 150% Magnification (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, windows-7, appearance, magnification

Windows 7 has added on its Control Panel, Appearance and Personalization, Display setting, an ability to Magnify the text and other items by 125% or 150%.

When that is done, some of the contents of the Forms and Dialogs of my Delphi 2009 program get cut off.

What changes do I need to make to ensure that all my forms and dialogs will look fine under any magnification setting on Windows 7.

Comment: I think I have a related issue - I use a component called the Apprehend Screen Capture http://www.hi-components.com/apprehend/
It used to be really nice, still is pretty nice, but hasn't been updated in a long time.  It does some rubberband-style capturing, where it makes a bitmap copy of the desktop, then shows that on a hidden form, so you can rubberband over that.  It gets all fouled up with the screen magnification. The only defense so far, is to run in compatibility mode with no video scaling.  Bummer.  I'm interested in seeing if these are related - I think so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're referring to the text size setting, which has existed in various forms in Windows for years, and Delphi forms' interactions with this setting and their automatic scaling.  I haven't got Windows 7 here to check, so I'm basing this only on your description.

Problems caused by this are **very common in Delphi applications**.  You may want to try setting the form's `Scaled` property to `false`, but read the information in these links first - doing that might not really be the best solution, but it depends on your program.

Try these links:

- This [very useful
  article](http://www.prestwoodboards.com/ASPSuite/KB/Document_View.asp?QID=100255)
  explains how common this is by
  saying, *"Does this sound familiar?
  You've finished that elegant form and
  polished the look and feel of the
  controls, and you send it off to your
  end user. And the first thing the
  user complains about is that the form
  is unreadable on their Windows PC.
  They complain that the text labels
  are chopped off, the edit controls
  run past the edge of the form, and
  the bottom of the form isn't even
  visible. What happened?"*.  Good thing it has a solution, hey :)
- This [delphi.about.com
  article](http://delphi.about.com/od/standards/a/aa030700a.htm)
  is also worth reading.

Hope that helps!

David